# Invoking a TCP SoapService using TcpClient

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, tcp

I have a demo soap service which echos back the request

```
 public class EchoWebService : SoapService
    {
        [SoapMethod("Echo")]
        public string Echo(string request)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request: {0}", request);
            return DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine + request;
        }
    }
```

Service is hosted using TCP,

```
Uri to = new Uri("soap.tcp://localhost:5696");
EndpointReference EPR = new EndpointReference(to);
SoapReceivers.Add(EPR, new EchoWebService());
```

I can invoke the service by writing my own TCP SoapClient,

```
Uri to = new Uri("soap.tcp://localhost:5696");
EndpointReference EPR = new EndpointReference(to);
mysoapclient client1 = new mysoapclient(EPR);
Console.WriteLine(client1.GetResponse("Hello World"));

class mysoapclient : SoapClient
{
        public mysoapclient(EndpointReference endpoint) : base(endpoint) { }
        public string GetResponse(string request)
        {

            return base.SendRequestResponse("Echo",
              request).GetBodyObject(typeof(string)).ToString();
        }
}
```

Is there any way to invoke the service using TcpClient? I want to send the raw xml over TCP to invoke the service and read the response back from the network stream. I tried using following code and xml but it doesn't seem to work.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 5696);
byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
byte[] response = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
client.GetStream().Read(response, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response));

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Echo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <request>Hello World</request>
    </Echo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill all binary headers to `SOAP/TCP`.

See [SUN's SOAP/TCP reference](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/apis-docs/soap-tcp-v1.0.pdf).

As a hint, you may run `tcpdump` or `wireshark`, record you `SOAP` session and see what exactly you need to fill.

To record loopback traffic, use `tcpdump` to capture it to the file, and open the file with `wireshark`

Comment: i tried using wireshark (along with all the hacks mentioned @ http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) but it doesn't capture loopback traffic on windows. tcpdump captured the loopback traffic but output wasn't meaningful.

Comment: I took a dump with tcpdump and opened the file in wireshark. When i followed the tcp stream i could only see following, 

. ...-.)....urn:uuid:406356e4-dc0f-4fb7-8dMIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart..
@..........